# Create view statement returns an empty result set

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a table called matchresults which has five columns named mresultid, playerid, seasonmatchid, rank, ratingsearned

mresultid is the primary key and playerid and seasonmatchid are foreign keys

The problem is that when I try to create a view on this table:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS matchresults_view;
CREATE  VIEW matchresults_view AS 
select mresultid, playerid, seasonmatchid 
from matchresults
where id = 8 ;
```

The query runs but it says mysql returned an empty result set. This is not true as I should be having two tuples in the result set.

What is wrong with the query?

Comment: Are you using the view later (select * from matchresults_view) to verify the view?

Comment: No am not verifying the view. Am just trying to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are creating a view. This command does not return any rows. It simply creates a view which you can think of as SQL query saved under a name, so that it is later possible to use in your queries. It will still execute the underlying SQL statement.

Now you have to query the view like below, to see what it outputs:

```
select * from matchresults_view
```

Comment: Oh yes it worked. I completely forgot that. Is there a way I can combine the two to have one query only? Like a query that creates the view and also asks to retrieve data from it.

Comment: No, it's not possible. That would need to be done within a function, but I think you are going the wrong way. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually I was just testing the view syntax on my database tables. Not trying to achieve anything specific. This is because it is said that views can be used to set what a particular employee in a company for example should be allowed to see from a table. That is just a simple example but I hope you get it.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: Sure, I got it. Yes, views are a way to easily manage data access :-) They don't take space on the disk, since they are just kind of a "wrapper" to hide the query behind it, but it still has to be executed. Materialized views are a different thing :-)